# Standard decomposition of vector-space endomorphism as direct sum of abelian groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-groups, free-modules

Let $V=\mathbb Q^7$, $\phi: V \rightarrow V$ the $\mathbb Q$-linear map given by the matrix:

$A=\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&1&0&2 \\0&2&1&0&0&-1&0\\0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&2&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&-2&-2 \\0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&0&0&1&1  \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}$

The characteristic polynomial is:

$P^c_{\phi}=X^7-9X^6+32X^5-55X^4+41X^3+2X^2-20X+8= (X-2)^3(X-1)^2(X^2-X-1)$

**Determine  $\operatorname {dim} [\operatorname{Ker}(\phi -id_V)] $ and  $\operatorname {dim} [\operatorname{Ker}(\phi -2id_V)] $. Write $(V, \phi )$, viewed as $Q[X]$-module, in standard form. [Hint: Use the dimensions  and the corollary below] and determine the minimum polynomial of $\phi$**

Note: Introducing a category Endom($k$). The objects of this category are pairs $(V, \phi) $ consisting of a $k$-vector space $V$ and an endomorphism $\phi$. We have that $k[X]-$module is isomorphic  to Endom($k$)

I determined that the rref of $A-I$ and $A-2I$ are

$A-I \sim \begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&2 \\0&0&0&0&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&0&0&0&0  \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}$
$A-2I \sim \begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\0&0&0&0&0&0&0  \end{pmatrix} \end{align*}$

so that

$\operatorname {dim} [\operatorname{Ker}(\phi -id_V)]= 1$

$\operatorname {dim} [\operatorname{Ker}(\phi -2id_V)]= 2$

but I have no idea how to write the standard form and find the minimal polynomial. Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT:

***My (partial) solution:***

I determined the the rref of $A-I$ and $A-2I$ and from them

$\operatorname {dim} [\operatorname{Ker}(\phi -id_V)]= 1$ and  $\operatorname {dim} [\operatorname{Ker}(\phi -2id_V)]= 2$

Now the standard form given by (1.4.2.1)consists in decomposing my vector space $V$ like this:

$V \cong Q[X]/(f_1) \oplus ...\oplus Q[X]/(f_t)$ , where the polynomials must be ordered such that $f_1|f_2...|f_t$. To do this I use corollary 1.4.7 so:

$P^c_{\phi}=f_1f_2...f_t$ where $f_t= P^{\operatorname min}_{\phi}$ is the minimum polynomial

So:$$(X-2)^3(X-1)^2(X^2-X-1)=f_1f_2...f_t$$

So some posibilities that satisfy  $f_1|f_2...|f_t$ are

i) $f_1=(X-2), f_2=(X-2)(X-1), f_3=(X-2)(X-1)(X^2-X-1)$

ii) $ f_1=(X-1)(X-2),f_2=(X-1)(X-2)^2(X^2-X-1)$

iii)$f_1=(X-2)^3(X-1)^2(X^2-X-1)$

maybe there are others ways

I must decide which  is the correct normal form. I am sure this is the procedure until this point.

Now to identify  the correct normal form, my guess is that I have to look at the dimensions of the eigenspaces is option i), because since I have eigenspaces of dimension 1 and 2 it's the only one where i have something of dimension 1 and something of dimension 2 and  that respects the condition $f_1|f_2...|f_t$, meaning $\mathbb Q/(X-2) $ of dim = 1,$\mathbb Q/(X-2) (X-1) $ of dim =2 and  $\mathbb Q/(X-2)(X-1)(X^2-X-1)$.  **However I am not sure if this is correct and more importantly why?** **I also don't know if I should be considering generalized eigenspaces instead.** Moreover I am not sure if  the fact that the characteristic polynomial the eigenvalue 2 has geometric multiplicity 2 while in the decomposition $(X-2)$ appears with exponent 1 in $\mathbb Q/(X-2) (X-1) $ of dim=2 and in $\mathbb Q/(X-2)(X-1)(X^2-X-1)$ of dim =4 should be a sign that it's wrong. I would have expected $\mathbb Q/(X-2)^2 $ as one of the factors to have a correspondence with the eigenspace of dim 2 of the eigenvalue 2, but then I wouldn't have the decomposition in normal form. That's again because I don't know the relation between algebraic and geometric multiplicities with the spaces in the decompositions.

Note: Example 1.1.6 below explains the isomorphism between a $k$-vector space together with an endomorphism, i.e. $(V,\phi)$ and $ K[X]$-modules.

You can find here

[docdroid.net/rpCR8ku/cathomalg-pdf](https://www.docdroid.net/rpCR8ku/cathomalg-pdf)

the lecture notes where this theorems come from

---

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: what book is this from?

Comment: @WillJagy These are lectures notes

Comment: The dimensions you counted tell you that there is a single Jordan block (if we pass to $\Bbb C$) with eigenvalue 1, and 2 blocks w/ EV 2. In this particular problem, it allows you to guess their sizes. Is 1.4.2 called the standard form?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist yes it is, could you please expand on your answer? this are the lecture notes by the way https://www.docdroid.net/rpCR8ku/cathomalg-pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Above the lecture notes

Comment: @some_math_guy Did you know before this course what the Jordan normal form is?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist Just in the setting of solving a system of ODE's using the matrix exponential, and not in an algebraic setting

Comment: How would multiplication by $g(X)$ (a $k$-irreducible polynomial) act on $k[X]/(f)$? Say $g(X) = X - \alpha$. If $f(X) = (X-\alpha)^m h(X)$, where $h(\alpha) \not = 0$, then what would be the $k$-dimension of the kernel of the multiplication map?

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist, I think the elements in the kernel must be of the form $(X-\alpha)^{m-1}h(X)$ so that when multplying by $(X-\alpha)$, I get $(X-\alpha)^mh(X)$ which is the same as $0$. So the dimension of the kernel of multiplication by that $g(X)$ is $m-1+deg(h)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $k[X]/(f(X))$, multiplication by $X-\alpha$ has kernel of dimension $0$ if $f(\alpha) \not = 0$ and dimension $1$ otherwise.

For your problem, it means that each $k[X]/(f_i)$ term in the standard form would either give $+1$ or $+0$ towards $\dim \ker(\phi - \alpha\,\text{id})$, depending on whether $f_i(X)$ is divisible by $X - \alpha$. Thus nonzero powers of $X - 1$ only occur in one of the $f_i$ (which one could it be?), and of $X - 2$, in two of them. So only one option to distribute the $f_i$ remains, namely, $i = 2$ and $f_1 = X-2$ (remember that $f_i$ divides $f_{i+1}$, and by by 1.4.7 $f_t$ is the minimal polynomial and $\prod_i f_i$ is the characteristical polynomial).

In general case, computing just the dimensions of $\ker(A-\lambda \,\text{id})$ won't be enough, you'll have to do the same to powers of $A-\lambda \,\text{id}$ until the sequence stabilizes for given $\lambda$. But that is probably known to you from the ODE course.

---

> so $(X−α)^{m−1}h(X)$ are the elements of the kernel, because they map to the 0 element $(X−α)^m h(X)$, since $(X−α)^{m−1} h(X)$ has degree $m−1+\deg h$, why isn't that the dim of the kernel?. I thought the dim of the kernel was the max degree of the polynomials in it. Otherwise how is it determined?

**Edit 1.** The quotient algebra $R = \Bbb Q[X]/(f)$ is a $\deg f$-dimensional vector space. For any $q \in \Bbb Q[X]$ the "multiplication by $q(X)$" map $m_q$ is a linear operator $R \to R$. For example, if you fix a basis of $R$, you could represent the operator as a matrix and forget about the polynomials at all. And its kernel $\ker m_q$ is first and foremost a linear subspace in $R$.

Now for its dimension in case $q = X - \alpha$ and $f = qh$. The algebra $R$ consists of *cosets* of polynomials wrt the ideal $(f)$, but in each of them we can fix exactly one representative whose degree is strictly lower than $f$'s. Let's work with these representatives. Suppose $v \in \ker m_q$. Then, as you said, the polynomial $v$ must be a multiple of $h$, but this implies that $v$ is either zero or has degree *at least* $\deg h$ — which is also the maximal possible degree among our representatives. So $v$ can only be a scalar multiple of $h$. That's a $1$-dimensional space worth of $v$'s.

> So it seems like the answer is that the decomposition is $\Bbb Q[X]/f_1 \oplus \Bbb Q[X]/f_2$, $f_1=(X−2)$ and $f_2=(X−2)^2(X−1)^2(X^2−X+1)$, correct? But I still don't see the rationale. what is the relationship between the $\dim \ker(ϕ−α id)$ and the exponents of the fact that the exponents of the $f_i$'s?

The rationale behind the choice is given in second paragraph of the first part of my post. Fix a $\lambda \in \Bbb Q$. When you act on $k[X]/(f_1) \oplus \ldots \oplus k[X]/(f_t)$ with $(A - \lambda I)$ by multiplication, it acts separately on all the direct summands. On some of these summands it will act like an invertible operator (with $0$-dimensional kernel), on some ones it will have (exactly!) $1$-dimensional kernels, and the kernel dimensions on summands add up to rank deficiency of the whole matrix $A - \lambda I$ (the numbers that you originally computed). Thus, as I said,

> nonzero powers of $X−1$ only occur in one of the $f_i$ (*the last one, i.e. the minimal polynomial*), and of $X−2$, in two of them.

The factor $X^2-X-1$ will obviously show up only in the minpoly too (as we have only one copy of it), so, as a maximum over the factors, $t$ will be equal to $2$. What's left to arrange is three copies of $X-2$ into two 'boxes' such that both boxes contain at least one copy and the second box can't contain less copies than the first.

---

**Edit 2.**

> 1. what do you mean by "the kernel dimensions on summands add up to rank deficiency"? what is rank deficiency? How is that the same as saying that the dimension of each kernel on direct summands add up to the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace?

Wikipedia: *The [rank deficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Main_definitions) of a matrix is the difference between the lesser of the number of rows and columns, and the rank.*

You can think of this in terms of the Jordan form over $\Bbb C$. Then the vector space $\Bbb C^7$ that $A$ acts upon splits into a direct sum of generalized eigenspaces, and each g. eigenspace further splits into smaller $A$-cyclic subspaces (cyclic = of form $\langle v, Av, \ldots \rangle$). You compute the $\ker (A - \lambda I)$ to isolate the true eigenvectors w/ e.val. $\lambda$ from the generalized EV's w/ $\lambda$ and unrelated vectors (well, we only need its dimension here, but I'm sure in ODE you also had to calculate the vectors). Each Jordan block w/ $\lambda$ gives exactly one $\lambda$-eigenvector, and thus the total number of Jordan blocks is equal to the dimension. Then you have to compute the kernel of the second power, which would contain the true e.vect. and the generalized e.vect of height 1, and so on.

In the problem you posted the situation is, in a way, more or less the same. The "standard form" (invariant factor) decomposition is more of a minimal-length description that still allows to recover the operator action, while the Jordan decomposition is "divide and conquer" until you get operators that act in a very simple way (the Jordan blocks). They are closely related, see the second bullet point of 1.3.13 and 1.4.9 for some examples.

> 2. why should I consider $A−λI$
>    to act on the standard decomposition? I mean, how is that connected to our analysis? I though we only had the map multiplication by a polynomial. First of all, how does a matrix act on a decomposition of polynomial spaces?

$A$ acts on $V$ by multiplication, and it is a linear operator. Same with the identity transformation $I$. For any two operators that act on $V$, their linear combination is still a linear operator on $V$, and so is their product. Since we have $I$, $A$, linear combinations and multiplication, we can assign a linear operator $p(A)$ to every polynomial $p(X) \in \Bbb Q[X]$. (In functional analysis, you can [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus) and use $p(A)$ even for more general continuous functions $p$, but that won't work for $\Bbb Q$ and is a digression anyway.)

The universe of polynomials $p(X)$ acting on $\Bbb Q[x]/(f_1) \oplus \ldots \oplus \Bbb Q[x]/(f_t)$ is parallel to the universe of $p(A)$'s and $V$. However, 1.4.2 states that the only things that differ between these two universes are labels on their elements, and the phenomena they exhibit are essentially the same. That's the meaning of the sentence right after 1.4.2.1 (a square commutative diagram, if you wish).

In my first edit, I identified the two universes without even thinking about it — formally and pedantically I was wrong, but from a practical viewpoint it was just an abuse of language. However in a course with 'Categories' in its name you should be really careful with such things :-)

Comment: Why is the first sentence true?, I don't see what $f(\alpha) $has to do with this

Comment: A polynomial $g(X)$ has a root at $\alpha$ if and only if $X - \alpha$ divides $g(X)$ in $k[X]$. That was just an alternative way of saying it (that alludes to the algebraic closure, where all irreducible polynomials are of degree 1 and we can meaningfully talk about eigenvalues).

Comment: Whether $f(\alpha)$ is zero or nonzero has to do with whether $X - \alpha$ divides $f(X)$, or whether $X - \alpha$ does not divide $f(X)$ (and therefore $X - \alpha$ and $f(X)$ are relatively prime).

Comment: @DanielSchepler OK, so $f(\alpha) \neq 0$ implies $(X-\alpha)$ does not divide $f(X)$, how does that imply the kernel of multiplication by $(X- \alpha)$ has dim $=0$?

Comment: If they're relatively prime, then $X - \alpha$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb{Q}[X] / \langle f(X) \rangle$.

Comment: (Since in $k[X]$ the remainder of $f(X)$ long-divided by $X-\alpha$ is a nonzero scalar $s$: $f(X) = g(X) (X - \alpha) + s$, we have $(X - \alpha) (-g(x)/s) = -f(X)/s + 1$, which is just $1$ in $k[X]/(f(X))$.)

Comment: Still not getting it sorry, I thought that the only invertible elements in polynomial rings over a field where the invertible elements of the field, $(X-\alpha)^{-1}$ is not a polynomial, but a power series. On the other hand let $m$ be multiplication by $(X-\alpha)$, then $Ker(m)=\{p \in \Bbb Q[X]/(f(X)): mv=(X-\alpha)p=0 \}$ , so if $X-\alpha$ is invertible $(X-\alpha)p=0 \implies p =0$, that's way the dim is $0$. (is this ok?)  if it is not invertible, what does the equation $(X-\alpha)p=0 $ imply for p to get dim=1?

Comment: $k[X]$ *is* a polynomial ring, $k[X]/(f(X))$ *is not* a polynomial ring. The conclusion in the invertible case is fine: just multiply both sides by the inverse of $(X - \alpha)$. In the noninvertible case we can conclude the same what you said in the first sentence of last comment to OP. (In the second sentence, you gave $\dim\, \text{Im}$ rather than $\dim \ker$.)

Comment: so $(X-\alpha)^{m-1}h(X)$ are the elements of the kernel, because they are map to the $0$ element$ (X-\alpha)^{m}h(X)$, since  $(X-\alpha)^{m-1}h(X)$ has degree $m-1 +$deg $h$, why isn't that the dim of the kernel?. I thought the dim of the kernel was the max degree of the polynomials in it. Otherwise how is it determined?

Comment: @DanielSchepler So it seems like the answer is that the decomposition is $\Bbb Q[X]/f_1 \Bbb Q[X]/f_2$ $f_1=(X-2)$ and f_2=$(X-2)^2(X-1)^2(X^2-X+1)$, correct? But I still don't see the rationale. what is the relationship between the $\dim \ker(\phi - \alpha\,\text{id})$ and the exponents of the fact that the exponents of the $f_i$'s?

Comment: Added some explanation under **Edit**.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it now

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "the kernel dimensions on summands add up to rank defficiency"? what is rank defficiency? How is that the same as saying that the dimension of each kernel on direct summands  add up to the dimension of the corresponding eigenspace?

Comment: 2) why should I consider $A-\lambda I$ to act on the standard decomposition? I mean, how is that connected to our analysis? I though we only had the map multiplication by a polynomial. First of all, how does a matrix act on a decomposition of polynomial spaces?

Comment: @some_math_guy Added a second edit.